# AGS 10.1 geoprocessing service returning the wrong URL

Tags: python, arcgis-server, arcgis-10.1, geoprocessing

I have an image export geoprocessing service that runs on ArcGIS server 10.1. It works by writing an image out to the scratch folder, and returning the location of that image.

Basically just this:

```
Output_File = os.path.join(arcpy.env.scratchFolder, output)
#Export the file ...
arcpy.SetParameterAsText(8, Output_File)
```

This works fine in most situations, and returns a url that looks like this:

```
http://www.oursite.com/arcgis/rest/directories/arcgisjobs/...
```

but on one client's network, when they connect to our hosted server, the service returns something that looks a lot more like this, despite the fact that the same instance of the service returns normally otherwise:

```
http://(local server name).(internal domain name).local:6080/arcgis/rest/directories/arcgisjobs/...
```

Is this the result of a misconfiguration on the server? And is there a reason why it would return the local network name of the server in some contexts?

Comment: Did they install the web adaptor?

Comment: This is when they connect to our server. I'm editing to clarify.

Comment: Not really sure, but it might be that the "localhost" or machine name was used when establishing the connection to the ArcGIS Server instead of fully qualified machine domain name (or IP address) depending on your scenario when publishing the GP service.

Comment: @AlexTereshenkov The app that's getting the weird responses uses the Javascript API, and a proxy for cross browser requests. Could it be that proxied requests are getting the strange urls?

Comment: @DanMonego Of course you never know, but I don't think so. The 6080 is the internal port used by ArcGIS Server by default. So it seems as the GP service result cannot be sent to the client with the right conversion of the local machine name and the port. Just a thought, though...

Comment: For others stumbling across this case in order to get a URL using "arcpy.SetParameterAsText(#, os.path.join(arcpy.env.scratchFolder, "myfile.zip"))" you must set the output type as file. See this case http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/75156/arcgis-server-geoprocessing-service-good-async-bad-sync

Answer (score 1):

You are going to have to do some basic network trouble shooting here.  First of all, are you going to the gp service directly and executing it? That should be the first step, if that works then you know its something with the way the javascript application is configured.

Assuming you have the same problem by executing the service directly in the browser, make sure you do not have a host resolution problem by using the IP address.

If you can narrow it down to the javascript viewer then open the network tab in chrome dev tools and investigate the results of the request.  Where is it sending the request?  What is it sending.  Post the results.